# Safe query parameters in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

I found a security risk in my application that I do not know how to fix. I just found this out while doing some checking on HTML and was playing with it.

So I have this code on a form tag

`<%= form_tag("/spree/admin/workorders/#{@workorder.id}
/?workflow_id=#{workflow.id}
&name=workstep_name_{workflow.product_workstep.workstep.name}
&workstep_id=#{workflow.product_workstep.workstep.id}", method: "put")do%>`

that query parameters will be caught by this method.

```
def update
        @incoming_status = params[params[:name]]
        # grab workflow, this is current data, use this to compare status to in comming status
        @workflow = get_workorder_product_workstep(params[:workflow_id])

        if is_workstep_for_shipping?
          if @workorder.order.shipment_state.downcase == "shipped"
            update_workflow
          else
             flash[:notice] = "Product not yet shipped"
          end
        else   
          update_workflow
        end

        redirect_to admin_workorder_path(@workorder)
      end
```

```
 def update_workflow
         # check current status if its pending allow to update
         if @workflow.send("can_#{@incoming_status}?")
          # update status
          @workflow.send(@incoming_status.to_s)
          # updated attribute handled_by
          @workflow.update_attributes(handled_by_id: @curr_user.id)
          @workflow.save
        else
          flash[:notice] = 'Action not allowed'
        end
      end
```

and on the browser, the form that was created in view will render this.

```
<form action="/spree/admin/workorders/45/?workflow_id=141&amp;name=workstep_name_w4&amp;workstep_id=61" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
</form>
```

now that form, those query parameters value can be changed. tried inputting wrong value and my backend crashed. how can fix this one? any idea or article that I could read? thank you.

**UPDATE**

While playing with the network. I also found this on network tab `request payload`

```
{spree_user: {email: "-----, password: "---"}}
spree_user: {email: "----", password: "----"}
```

everything is on plain text. I just changed my email and password to ----

If a person with a tech background they can easily spot this.

The code is from production. I think we are not using JWT here.

Comment: What do you mean by "my backend crashed"? The backend stopped working? some page raised an error after that form submission? It returns a 500 error for the user that does nasty things with the code? One thing you can do is to just send the workflow_id, since `name` and `workstep_id` are just built using that workflow associations, if you get the workflow on the controller you can get the rest.

Comment: @arieljuod yea backend stopped working. hmm. I didn't think of that. I guess I can do that on the controller level since they're all associated.